# having problem with installing Python package

Tags: python, package

I want install python package. But when I am trying to install "ipython" package and I write:

```
pip install ipython
```

It give this error:

```
pip install ipython
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Where are you executing this command? What operating system do you have?

Comment: I write these in command prompt. and I use Windows 8.1 64 bits

Comment: Try using `python -m pip install ipython` or `!pip install ipython`

Comment: That is a python shell error, not a command line error. You are not at the command prompt.

Comment: Go to your cmd, then enter your command.

Comment: @tdelaney in cmd I write python. and I am in python environment. Do you mean I should open python Shell?

Comment: @CeliusStingher I tried both but they didn't work

Comment: In cmd and you write python, you are now in the python shell where python syntax is required. You should be able to `exit()` back to the command prompt and then type the command.

Comment: You can also exit with Ctrl+Z and then try either of my suggestions

Comment: Oh thank you CeliusStingher and tdelaney  It is now installing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a bit confusing at first, but python is a very different shell than the windows `cmd` shell or any of the unixy shells. Once you've entered python, only python syntax is allowed. Mostly.... there are other shells such as Jupyter notebook and various IDE's that will have extensions to do non-python things.

Since a python error was displayed `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` it showed that your command had in fact ended up in the python interpreter. The solution is to run the comamnd directly from the command prompt.